# Word for a specific enzymatic process?

Tags: terminology, enzymes

### Foreword:

I am developing a variable-processing program for my Computer Science research project.

One particular part of the program mimics the behavior of biological enzymes, except instead of catalyzing break downs and compositions of chemicals, its catalyzing break downs and compositions of variables (specifically arrays).

### The *process in question* is a 2 part process:

> - initiating process:
>
>   - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **breaks down** certain compounds **<kbd>into smaller compounds</kbd>**
>   - *(in terms of program:)* **fragments** certain variables (certain arrays) **<kbd>into fragments</kbd>**
> - finalizing process:
>
>   - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **combine** the smaller compounds **<kbd>into larger compounds different from the originals</kbd>** (*like mixing and matching the parts*)
>   - *(in terms of program:)* **combine** the fragment-variables **<kbd>into larger variables different from the originals</kbd>** (*like mixing and matching the parts*)

### The *process in question* all together:

> - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **breaks down** certain compounds **<kbd>into smaller compounds</kbd>**,
>   then **recombines** them **<kbd>into larger compounds that are different from the original large compounds</kbd>** 
>   (*like mixing and matching the parts*)
> - *(in terms of program:)* **fragments** certain variables (certain arrays) **<kbd>into fragments</kbd>** 
>   then **recombines** them **<kbd>into larger variables that are different from the original large variables</kbd>** 
>   (*like mixing and matching the parts*)

### What is the *process in question* called?

### Afternote:

I'm looking for a **name**, so the word could be a new word constructed from recognizable Latin or Germanic roots, and that would be an acceptable answer.

To get full coverage of an answer, I asked this question the [English Language & Usage SE site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354536/word-for-an-enzymatic-process), [Stackoverflow SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165920/term-for-break-down-and-re-composition-of-arrays-in-programming), and this SE site.

Comment: the purpose of asking on the different sites is to get different types of feedback, so if you want to provide an answer on each site, please be considerate and don't dupe your answers. Answer with a different light and perspective. I am trying to get a full-coverage answer

Comment: Cross-posting questions on multiple sites is generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). It would probably be better if you decided which perspective suited you the best and asked it on one single site.

Comment: With that said, I'll give you two chemical options: *rearrangement* and *isomerisation*.

Comment: "Digestion" and "ligation" sound good to me.  So do "lysis" and "agglomerization".   Calling the combined process a "recombination" or even a "fermentation" seems apt.

Comment: In the broadest sense, "catabolic" for breakdown and "anabolic" for reconstruction might be suitable. Not sure what the two together would be, though.

Comment: @hBy2Py [Amphibolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibolic) describes that. // general comment: OP is looking for a word to describe the entire process, not the individual break down and build up components. It's very common to say that "XXX enzyme catalyses the isomerisation of ABC to DEF". This class of enzymes even have their own name: isomerases. Hence my original proposal.

Comment: To add onto the existing comments, "catamorphism" and "anamorphism"  are existing programming terms for functions that do something like what you describe. While we could inappropriately transplant terms and call your process a "amphimorphism," I'm pretty sure you'd just be better off just describing exactly what you're doing. If you use a single word that's  unknown or with an ambiguous meaning, your documentation isn't of much use to anyone.